# How to force a compiler to choose a specific function specialization

Tags: c++, templates

For example, I have two classes:

```
class Foo {
public:
    const bool operator==(const Foo&) const;

    template<class _Ty>
    const bool operator==(const _Ty&) const;
};

class Bar : public Foo { };
```

And code like this:

```
Foo& foo;
Bar& bar;

const bool equality = (foo == bar);
```

Obviously, a compiler will choose the template function to evaluate this expression because variable `bar` need to be converted to `Foo&` to call the specialized `operator==`. But is there any way how I can force a compiler (without casting `Bar&` into `Foo&`) to choose the specialization firstly instead of the template function when the argument is an instance of a class derived from `Foo` (e.g. add/remove some modifiers or something else)?

Comment: You can try to cast Bar into Foo.

Comment: @Chnossos Yes, I can. But actually question is about exactly this expression, without casting `Bar&` into `Foo&`. :)

Comment: @Chnossos I edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: Whithout casting, the only solution that comes to my mind is changing the first function so that it is a specialization of the second for Foo type, and then call your comparison like `foo.operator==<Foo>(bar)` but that's kinda ugly ...

Comment: @Chnossos Another is to leave only the template operator which would call a private comparison function (which would declared in the same way as the operators in the question but with some dummy parameters to change theirs priority). But I don't know if it is really good solution.

Comment: Why would you need something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way how I can force a compiler (without casting Bar& into Foo&) to choose the specialization firstly instead of the template function when the argument is an instance of a class derived from Foo?

Yes, you can, using *type traits*. Specifically you can use [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) as follows:

```
template<typename Type>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_base_of<Foo, Type>::value,
    const bool
>::type
operator==(const Type&) const { … }

template<typename Type>
typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_base_of<Foo, Type>::value,
    const bool
>::type
operator==(const Type&) const { … }
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b2d5780cedba4a2)

You basically activate/deactivate an overload based on template argument.

You can also make things *slightly* more readable by adding an alias:

```
template<class Type>
using is_fooable = std::is_base_of<Foo, Type>;
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd28ce5703100d88)

Comment: +1: but myself, I would tag dispatch the arguments to an `bool equal(Foo const&, std::true_type)` and `bool equal(T const&, std::false_type)`, as that removes the needless `template`ing of the `Bar` implementation.  Oh and the `const` is at the wrong spot -- you want to return `bool` but take a `const` object instance.

Comment: @Yakk, what do you mean by `const` is in the wrong spot, exactly?

Comment: The return value of your function should be `bool` not `const bool` -- there are very, very, very few valid reasons to return `const` value types.

Comment: @Yakk, Hmm. Why would you ever want to reassign that temporary object (the one returned by `x == y`)? IIRC, in one of his books, Scott Meyer recommended this practice.

Comment: if it is a basic type, no difference.  If non basic, `const` blocks effective `move` out of temporary if the move is not elided.  Rather, block `operator=` from operating with an lvalue lhs (mimicing basic types).